# Images missing from Blog post page

Tags: images, post-thumbnails

I have created a blog named [Tutsguru](https://www.tutsguru.com/). When i visit [Main page](https://www.tutsguru.com/) it shows feature images of blog post but when i visit [Blog page](https://www.tutsguru.com/blog/) then images are not shown. I tried different browser but same problem.

Can you please tell me whats the problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since your theme puts a default image in place of a not-found image, it's hard to tell why the images aren't there.

But, I'd suspect an error in the theme template that displays your blog page. You would need to look at the theme template code to see what code is being used to show the image (or to show the default image when the image is not found).

If you post the code from your template that displays the blog page, we could help. But, your best bet is to contact the theme developer's support area.

(All of this assumes that the images are there; which they apparently are, since the images show up on the other page.)

*(Note: posted as an answer instead of a comment due to length limitations.)*